# I need to set up a task to run a batch file in 32 cmd.exe

Tags: batch-file, windows-7, cmd, 64-bit, scheduled-tasks

In windows 7 (64 bit) if I do a search for %windir%\SysWoW64\cmd.exe and open it, it will open a 32 bit instance of cmd.exe.  From there, if I was doing this manually, I could then run my batch file and everything is good to go.

Now, when I set up a task and run the same batch file...doesn't work.  Probably because the 64 bit cmd.exe is being launched.

Another caveat...I can't just change the windows environment variables to always point to the 32 bit version, because I have other batch files that need 64 bit...

So, somehow, I need to be able to set up a task via Windows task scheduler where the task itself knows to launch the 32 bit cmd.exe and run the batch file in that instance of cmd.exe.

Any ideas?

Comment: Launch the batch file from the 32-bit `cmd`? Use this for the scheduled task: `"%windir%\SysWoW64\cmd.exe /c"`, with `"C:\Whatever\YourFile.bat"` as the parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe I am missing the mark, but you canset your Program in the Action tab to be C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe then pass the script as an argument

Like so:
[image]

Comment: Just noticed Ken left a comment saying the same while I was grabbing a screenshot, I'll leave the pic but he pretty much answered it.  you will need to put the /c with the arguments though and not at the end of the cmd.exe here.

Comment: Thanks.  I will give this a try tomorrow morning and WHEN it works...mark the answer as correct.  Thanks for the response guys.